# Google search by date?

Tags: google-search

How can I list all Google search hits in order of date of page modification or indexing rather than by rank?

Answer (score 3):

http://code.google.com/apis/searchappliance/documentation/68/xml_reference.html

See "Sort by Date".

Comment: Thanks! Here is the direct link: http://code.google.com/apis/searchappliance/documentation/68/xml_reference.html#request_sort_by_date